# PYTHON ERROR OperationalError: near "ident": syntax error when i try to introduce UNIQUE constraint

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to name some columns as unique in my SQLite table, but I get an error for the next column field when I do. In this table, it's the ident column. can someone tell me why?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAWXu.png)  when I try to execute the table, it does not work. If I try this without the UNIQUE constraint, it works. But I need the unique control to avoid duplicates in the table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jbRC.png)
 `run_table = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS runways( id INTEGER UNIQUE, airport_ref INTEGER, airport_ident TEXT); #create table into database c.execute(run_table)`

Comment: unable to reproduce that error. something else is going on. are you using the built-in `sqlite3` module, or something else?

Comment: yes using sqlite3 built in

Comment: ah i realised where i went wrong. I forgot to add a comma in after UNIQUE. always the obvious mistake! Thank you however